# find priority from urgency and_impact using msql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter-2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maxgw.png)

```html
<div class="row float-left">

  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Impact</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select name="sla" class="form-control">
    <option>Select </option>
              <?php if(count($sla_list)):?>
     <?php foreach($sla_list as $sla_lists):?>
     <option value=<?php echo $sla_lists->name;?>> <?php echo $sla_lists->name; set_select('name');?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
     <?php endif; ?>

    </select>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <?php echo form_error('sla'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Priority</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select name="priority" class="form-control">
    <option>Select </option>
              <?php if(count($priority_list)):?>
     <?php foreach($priority_list as $priority):?>
     <option value=<?php echo $priority->name;?>> <?php echo $priority->name; set_select('name');?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
     <?php endif; ?>

    </select>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <?php echo form_error('priority'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

// i want to set severity automatically from database table have two different table one have value h/m/l and other have p1 /p2/p3 by multiplying the matrices i want to show severity depend on dynamically selected dropdown how to do it in codeiginter

Comment: can you ask more clearly? what do you want?

Comment: sir ,i want to get severity from impact and urgency so can you help me with mysaql database how to make matrices to get severity from impact and urgency of any incident means when i click on dropdown of impact (e.g high,medium,low)and urgency(e.g priority p1,p2,p3) it automatically give me an output by multiplying both

Comment: how to make controller and model to get matrices multiplication i have added i have done with priority and impact as above in code you can see  and image please find attachement